# I feel flattered means the same thing as I'm flattered?

Tags: vocabulary

**Flatter** is when you compliment someone in a way that is not sincere.
To **be flattered** although is kinda saying "it's so nice of you"
And what about "I **feel flattered**"?

Comment: Flattery doesn't necessarily involve insincerity—in fact, it often doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed by Jason Bassford and according to the Cambridge Dictionary, *flatter* doesn't imply **always** insincerity.

> [**flatter**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flatter)
>   to praise someone in order to make them feel attractive or important, **sometimes** in a way that is not sincere

In the linked page you can also find the following definition indicating that **be flattered = feel flattered**

> **be/feel flattered**
>  to feel very pleased and proud because someone has
>   said good things about you or has made you feel important